# install ImageMagick on xampp 1.8.3

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I want to use ImageMagick.Currently i am using

```
PHP version: 5.5.9
Windows Version: Windows 8 Pro  64-bit
XAMPP Version: 1.8.3
Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
```

i tried all dll that in available to [this](https://www.peewit.fr/imagick/) site
Now when i lunch xampp every time it says

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' 
- %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

i also tried these binary [binary-releases](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

although it install successfully in `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16` but i am still not able to use these on xampp

Please point me in right direction and tell me how can i install ImageMagick in xampp

Comment: I have the same problem, have you get it work?.
I tried many versions, but still  **%1 is not a valid Win32 application**

Answer (score 1):

I Guess all your PHP dll files (librarires) are 32 bit, so if your system is 64 bit and you will still need to download and operate 32 bit ImageMagick.Your error also said

```
'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application //win32
```

For more info see following link here but first download compatible dll file, best of luck

http://www.elxsy.com/2009/07/installing-imagemagick-on-windows-and-using-with-php-imagick/

Comment: Thanks for your help but most of the links are dead on your page and when i installed imagick from here [link](http://imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows).it installed successfully but still not getting required dll for xampp

Comment: i have successfully complete step 3 but links available in step 4 are dead

Comment: will you please give me another suggestion

Comment: This links may help you, your main problem is correct version of .dll

http://www.sk89q.com/2010/03/vc6-windows-binaries-for-imagick-2-3-0/    
http://originaldll.com/file/php_imagick.dll/30715.html

Comment: thanks for your replay but the below link is for php 5.3.3 .is it also work for php 5.5.9

Comment: There is a download link in this page, this may work for you http://www.clintbrownweb.com/content/imagemagick-windows-8

Comment: sorry to say that but download link on these pages is also dead. all page will give the same path